# Printing flask server logs on console

Tags: flask, service, console, output

I have a flask server running in background i.e. created a .service file and initiated the flask application. Now, when I fire flask APIs from launcher file, I am unable to see logger messages on console. I wrote below code to get the output to console, which is not the efficient way

```
#log_file is populated by flask logging i.e. fileHandler

pro = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n0", "-f", log_file])    

#this is to terminate the process once launcher file exits

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

I am doing this to add verbosity option to my launcher for example if user gives "launcher.py -v", it should print INFO, ERROR, WARN and DEBUG messages.

I am new to python and went through documentation as well, couldn't figure out a way.
Can someone suggest the right way to do this ?

**Note:** If I launch the application normally, I can see output on console as I have added StreamHandler(sys.out) to logger.

Comment: I assume you're running on linux, given mention of the .service file. In that case, you should use `journalctl` to see the logfile output. To your specific service's logs, use `journalctl -u nameofmyservice`

Comment: @JamesMcPherson journalctl is displaying each line twice, one from StreamHandler and one from FileHandler, how do I remove these duplicate lines ?

I need the output which is coming to sys.out as I have formatted it to be user friendly. FileHandler has all debug messages such as python file name, line number etc...

Comment: Turn off the FileHandler then :)

Comment: @JamesMcPherson I need fileHandler for future debug purposes

Comment: FileHandler should be redirected to an actual logfile that isn't stdout or stderr.